# Google Analytics API monthly data increases with longer selected date range

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've stumbled upon this problem and have no idea how to explain. I want to view number of events month-by-month, therefore, I included parameters drilled down by yearMonth dimension:

`metrics = ga:users and ga:uniqueEvents
dimension = ga:yearMonth
filter = ga:eventCategory==Installed`

I made 2 requests for a different time ranges (2016 up to now and 2015 up to now):

For 2016 only I got these numbers:
[image]

then expanded range to 2015 and 2016:
[image]

surprisingly numbers for February changed!! and became bigger over longer period of time (logically it should go down as per cookie). I've tried to include different sampling options in requests and numbers didn't change, I believe problem isn't in sampling.

Comment: "I believe problem isn't in sampling."   How do you know?

Comment: Did you check the `containsSampledData` attribute of the responses for both queries? If one contains sampled data but the other doesn't, that's a good candidate for the discrepancy.

Comment: @dorian yes, you are right!! And it's roughly 75% wow. It's just I tried different sampling options but results never changed. Do you know what is the threshold of sessions for sampling to start?

Comment: Not exactly, but this page might have some more information: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2637192